# Web Scrapping (ecommerce) - empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap an eCommerce site by using beautiful soup. I've noticed that the HTML of the main page is coming incomplete. In addition, my python list is coming empty when I try to find almost any item.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content,"lxml")

productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='items-IW-')

print(productlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can use `requests` to simulate it. For example:

```py
import json
import requests


url = "https://8r21li.a.searchspring.io/api/search/search.json"

params = {
    "resultsFormat": "native",
    "resultsPerPage": "24",
    "page": "1",
    "siteId": "8r21li",
    "bgfilter.ss_category": "Women",
}

data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for r in data["results"]:
    print("{:<50} {:<10}".format(r["name"], r["price"]))
```

Prints:

```
KMDCore Polypro Long Sleeve Unisex Top             29.98     
Andulo Women's Rain Jacket v3                      139.98    
Epiq Women's 600 Fill Hooded Down Jacket           199.98    
KMDCore Polypro Unisex Long Johns                  29.98     
Heli Women's Hooded Lightweight Down Vest          70        
Accion driMOTION Low Cut Unisex Socks – 3Pk        31.49     
Pocket-it Women’s Two Layer Rain Jacket            70        
Unisex Thermo Socks 2Pk                            34.98     
NuYarn Ergonomic Unisex Hiking Socks               34.98     
KMDCore Polypro Short Sleeve Unisex Top            29.98     
Fyfe Unisex Beanie                                 17.49     
Makino Travel Skort                                79.98     
Miro Women’s 3/4 Pants                             69.98     
Ridge 100 Women’s Primaloft Bio Pullover           59.98     
Epiq Women's 600 Fill Down Vest                    149.98    
Epiq Women's 600 Fill Down Jacket                  179.98    
Flinders Women’s Pants                             89.98     
Flight Women’s Shorts                              59.98     
ANY-Time Sweats Joggers                            79.98     
Kamana Women’s Tapered Pants                       89.98     
NuYarn Ergonomic Quarter Crew Unisex Hiking Socks  31.49     
Bealey Women’s GORE-TEX Jacket                     190       
Winterburn Women’s 600 Fill Longline Down Coat     299.98    
Kathmandu Badge Unisex Beanie                      27.98
```

Comment: That's good to know, thanks!
Can I ask how did you find that external URL?
https://8r21li.a.searchspring.io/api/search/search.json

Comment: @DamiánGómez You can see the URL in Firefox Developer Tools->Network tab (or in Chrome). There are all requests the page is doing.